# Converting layer with symbology using multiple attributes to KML file using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, kml, symbology, fields-attributes

I'm trying to convert a point feature layer with a symbology that uses multiple attributes (a color-scheme attributed to the percentage of positive malaria cases and a symbol size attributed to the number of cases evaluated) into a KML file using the coversion toolbox of ArcGIS 10.1.

Unfornately, when attempting this using the Layer to KML tool, the resulting KML file does not retain the full color-scale defined in the original point feature layer; it represents the symbol sizes correctly, but all the points are reprensented in only 2 types colors (dark and light green). However, a full scale of dark green to dark red should be represented in this KML file similarly to the original point feature layer displayed in ArcGIS 10.1.

I've also tried using the Map to KML tool, but I obtained the same results.

Is it possible to convert a point feature layer with a symbology using multiple attributes to a KML file via the Conversion tool box of ArcGIS 10.1, without losing any elements of the symbology?

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem. Layer in ArcGIS 10.3 symbolised so that one numeric variable determines point colour and another determines point size.

When exported using Layer to KML tool, the resulting KMZ file in Google Earth looks extremely pixelated - although all five colour bins are preserved, points look more like squares than circles.

The solution is to open the KMZ file with 7-zip, extract the png symbol files, up-res them manually and save back into the KMZ under the same name. It works.